# FOSUserBundle understanding twig template variables

Tags: symfony, templates, twig, fosuserbundle

In the layout.html.twig file;

```
{% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
        {{ 'layout.logged_in_as'|trans({'%username%': app.user.username}, 'FOSUserBundle') }} |
        <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">
            {{ 'layout.logout'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
        </a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}">{{ 'layout.login'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</a>
    {% endif %}
```

What is the layout property referring to? It just seems to output the string as it is in my html page ie 'layout.logged_in_as' and 'layout.logout'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the translations keys as is common for Symfony bundles
.

Here are [the `layout` translation definitions that would be translated to English](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.en.yml#L73):

```
layout:
  logout: 'Log out'
  login: 'Log in'
  register: Register
  logged_in_as: 'Logged in as %username%'
```

Comment: Ah makes sense. How do I configure my application to use the translations?

Comment: Symfony translator is usually disabled by default in new projects (since not all apps need translating). To enable it, [just add the `framework.translator` config key as mentioned in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#translations).